# Sort files into subfolders acoording to name [script]

Tags: scripts, files, sort

I have several files which were recovered from a backup but have the structure (file location) as the file name.

eg:

```
C\Users\Welcome\Desktop\Doc1.docx
F\New folder\concerts\0904M002.WAV
```

I want to make a script that takes these names one by one and creates the respective folders and place the file inside the folder.

for eg: F\New folder\concerts\0904M002.WAV

--> Make a folder "F" on current directory then cd to F make a folder "New folder" similarly make "concerts" (or directly do mkdir F\New folder\concerts)

--> rename the file "F\New folder\concerts\0904M002.WAV " to "0904M002.WAV " and move it to the newly created folder "F\New folder\concerts\"

Can some one help me with the script?
Thanks

Comment: Those files were backed up from windows but i am on linux. it was done with a program that packs all files into a zip renaming each file for their path. i have forgotten the name of the program so now i have to manually extract the zip and rename the file and move them into their respective  folders .

Comment: Ok, I believe you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following bash script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *\\*
do 
    destFile="${file//\\/\/}"
    destFolder="${destFile%/*}"
    [ -d "$destFolder" ] || mkdir -p "$destFolder"
    mv -v "$file" "$destFile"
done
```

The code basically replaces all the `\` in the source file with `/` to get the destination file path. Then it gets the destination directory of the file and creates it using `mkdir -p`. Finally the file is copied to the destination folder.

Write the code into a file (let us say `script.sh`) and then in terminal do

> ```
> $ chmod +x script.sh
> $ ./script.sh
> ```

Comment: No need to use `sed` since Bash has pattern substitution: `destFile="${file//\\/\/}"`. And `$(dirname "$destFile")` could be replaced by `${destFile%/*}`. Guarding the `mkdir` invocation with a condition `[ -d "${destFile%/*}" ] || mkdir ...` can also save a bunch of slow, expensive fork+exec calls.

Comment: I would however suggest     mv -pv "$file" "$destFile" instead of     cp -pv "$file" "$destFile"

Comment: @DavidFoerster. Thank you for the suggestions to improve the code.  I have edited the code to include the suggestions.